# React-native: how to disable the opening of dev-tools webbrowser tab?

Tags: react-native, debugging

Starting my app with `react-native start` (when debug mode is enabled) open a tab in my default webbrowser (after the log `info Launching Dev Tools...` displayed in the terminal).

How can I disable it?

Comment: In order to disable opening new tab you need to disable debug mode

Comment: Thanks, I know I could disable opening new tab this way, but I don't want to disable debug mode.

Answer (score 10):

In menu of the device press 'Stop Debugging'.
In my case (Android, Samsung phone), it's 2nd point, the 1st is 'Reload'.
If debug is stopped all console.log go to the terminal where Metro Bundler is run.